# New item inserted in Azure Table Storage is not immediately available

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-table-storage

**I have**

- an endpoint in an Azure Function called "INSERT" that that inserts a
  record in Table Storage **using a batch operation**.
- an endpoint in a different Azure Function
  called "GET" that gets a record in Table Storage.

**If I insert an item and then immediately get that same item, then the item has not appeared yet!**

If I delay by **one second** after saving, then **I find** the item.

If I delay by **10ms** after saving, then **I don't find** the item.

I see the same symptom when updating an item. I set a date field on the item. If I get immediately after deleting, then some times the date field is not set yet.

**Is this known behavior in Azure Table Storage?** I know about ETags as described [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/managing-concurrency-in-microsoft-azure-storage-2/) but I cannot see how it applies to this issue.

I cannot easily provide a code sample because this is distributed among multiple functions and I think if I did put it in a simpler example, then there would be some mechanism that would see I am calling from the same ip or with the same client and manage to return the recently saved item.

Comment: Are you using Azure Storage Tables or Cosmos DB Table API? In case of latter, please check the consistency type.

Comment: I am using Azure Table Storage, not Cosmos DB

Comment: This is weird because AFAIK, Azure Table is strongly consistent.

Comment: Check your storage logs. This will show whether the POST and GET were properly sequenced or are overlapping. I suspect that your INSERT is returning before the underlying POST to storage completes.

Comment: Michael, thanks. Do you mean the 'Dependency tracking I can get from Application Insights. Or is it a raw text log somewhere?

Comment: @GauravMantri would you like to put your comment about strongly consistent as an answer? Because that is really the right answer in all its simplicity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, Azure Table Storage is **Strongly Consistent**. Data is available to you as soon as it is written to Storage.

This is in contrast with Cosmos DB Table Storage where there are many consistency levels and data may not be immediately available for you to read after it is written depending on the consistent level set.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was related to my code and queues running in the background.

I had shut down the Function that has queue triggers but to my surprise I found that the Function in my staging slot was picking items off the queue. That is why it made a difference whether I delay for a second or two.

And to the second part, why a date field is seemingly not set as fast as I get it. Well, it turns out I had filtered by columns, like this:

```
var operation = TableOperation.Retrieve<Entity>(partitionKey, id, new List<string> { "Content", "IsDeleted" });
```

And to make matters worse, the class "Entity" that I deserialize to, of course had default primitive values (such as "false") so it didn't look like they were not being set.

So the answer does not have much to do with the question, so in summary, for anyone finding this question because they are wondering the same thing:

The answer is **YES** - Table Storage is in fact strongly consistent and it doesn't matter whether you're 'very fast' or connect from another location.